# How to fill variables with the content of a Json

Tags: json, powershell, webhooks

I'm starting to work with PowerShell and my first task is to fix a problem with a script that already runs in the production environment.

This script is called via Webhook and it receives a parameter that the webhook passes to it.

I need to run this script inside PowerShell ISE to be able to debug it but I don't know how to fill the variables that are normally filled when it is called by Webhook.

Here is the beginning of the code where the variables are filled in, can someone give me a tip on how to fill the variable "WebHookData"..?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to do this but it didn't work...

[image]

Sorry for putting images instead of the code, but for some reason I can't post the code.

This is the JSON that I use..

```
{"source":"la-draft-clipboard","value":[{"tokenKey":"8EAD3F03-E08F-4D58-8B1A-2AB8BD2F25DB","type":"literal","tokenExpression":"{"},{"tokenKey":"A7596123-17DF-49A9-AC18-1196A4CD457E","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"36DF511D-C1A9-4BC8-B2E9-37BCA058FB78","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"AutomationAccountName\": \"proj-00016-automation-account\","},{"tokenKey":"918137AE-EC61-4B77-A5F2-B527E2D4E3C9","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"DCC2D1C1-14F0-4869-A44C-08F8AB35B0B3","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"BeginPeakTime\": \"7:00\","},{"tokenKey":"61F7441B-0688-4AD2-A1A5-086C4F7F6D1E","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"2F3DD3CA-BD83-46EF-9529-C890C2E31CAF","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"ConnectionAssetName\": \"AzureRunAsConnection\","},{"tokenKey":"C6DD6FD0-E99A-48A8-96AA-3974D66FD9BD","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"A4E7A469-D08A-4C5A-8C6B-06E58996A0EC","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"EndPeakTime\": \"17:00\","},{"tokenKey":"E67547BC-98BB-4749-A84E-A36B761EE504","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"727D64BD-906C-4DA3-84C5-44F3054B2DEB","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"HostPoolName\": \"VDI-POOL-001\","},{"tokenKey":"92AFEBB8-4307-42C2-8BD0-C55ACC848940","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"F37993F9-1471-4E58-B43F-9BB08C4D4A03","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"LimitSecondsToForceLogOffUser\": 0,"},{"tokenKey":"8B2517D1-046E-43EF-BF75-B1EC5F31B83D","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"7464316E-6A8D-4F82-B269-95FF76A69014","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"LogOffMessageBody\": \"Salve seus trabalhos! Em aproximadamente 15 minutos, este terminal virtual será desligado automaticamente devido às políticas de otimização de custos da companhia. Caso seja necessário continuar suas atividades, um novo terminal poderá ser acessado após este período.\","},{"tokenKey":"7328955E-0025-4AA1-A0AE-CDAFA4238927","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"384AF3CF-CA86-4820-A5E1-230C09909662","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"LogOffMessageTitle\": \"ATENÇÃO!!!\","},{"tokenKey":"5E2EBD78-8599-487F-8DC5-CF9699595DDD","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"B7E409AF-A5AE-4622-A45E-5982FD15B03E","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"MaintenanceTagName\": \"NO_TAG\","},{"tokenKey":"3F9BF963-790D-45B1-9F04-D71A2B7C84DC","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"B6E94E37-69C0-4BF8-AE69-CD7B4EA9CB83","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"MinimumNumberOfRDSH\": 20,"},{"tokenKey":"00A1D37B-F82B-42F6-B792-75B39EBD6A83","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"F41B0C75-4541-4772-BF30-2D4F6DF045C6","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"ResourceGroupName\": \"proj-00016-wvd-rg\","},{"tokenKey":"FE6FC329-DC12-4782-83CE-F48BDC6B74B5","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"785500F8-3D71-4D91-AADA-D6ABF1EFD66B","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"ResourceGroupNameAutomation\": \"proj-00016-automation-rg\","},{"tokenKey":"BD3331BF-3BF9-4B9E-B9B8-C03E448B2D85","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"25586050-62A0-4CAF-81FD-C5770DF20B63","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"RunbookLogoffShutdown\": \"ARMLogoffAndShutdown\","},{"tokenKey":"C4B9E432-C41D-4374-9531-F2AEFDD51267","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"0155B6AB-7CAB-4C4E-BB1F-A643D9B0575B","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"SessionThresholdPerCPU\": 0.75,"},{"tokenKey":"3EAA1C7E-0119-40B9-9AF8-85D10E0FA3FD","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"2D904698-1386-47D7-9513-7CEE702BA0D3","type":"literal","tokenExpression":" \"TimeDifference\": \"-3:00\""},{"tokenKey":"40D497B6-AAED-4334-81C7-10B8C6745DE0","type":"new_line","tokenExpression":"\n"},{"tokenKey":"18EB90AF-25D4-4956-8A85-41BA555C6A95","type":"literal","tokenExpression":"}"}]}
```

Comment: Please post your code as plain text at the bottom of your question body - we can help you format it correctly after the fact. The title of your question says "with the content of a Json" - but you didn't post any JSON... Do you have a sample json payload that's usually sent to the webhook?

Comment: `$json.Value.tokenexpression | ConvertFrom-Json`  seems to be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JSON you've posted and the parts of the code we can see in the screenshot, give the following mock object a try:

```
$mockWebhookPayload = [pscustomobject]@{
  WebhookName   = 'NameOfWebhookGoesHere'
  RequestHeader = @{ 'Content-Type' = 'application/json' }
  RequestBody   = @'
{
   "AutomationAccountName": "proj-00016-automation-account",
   "BeginPeakTime": "7:00",
   "ConnectionAssetName": "AzureRunAsConnection",
   "EndPeakTime": "17:00",
   "HostPoolName": "VDI-POOL-001",
   "LimitSecondsToForceLogOffUser": 0,
   "LogOffMessageBody": "Salve seus trabalhos! Em aproximadamente 15 minutos, este terminal virtual será desligado automaticamente devido às políticas de otimização de custos da companhia. Caso seja necessário continuar suas atividades, um novo terminal poderá ser acessado após este período.",
   "LogOffMessageTitle": "ATENÇÃO!!!",
   "MaintenanceTagName": "NO_TAG",
   "MinimumNumberOfRDSH": 20,
   "ResourceGroupName": "proj-00016-wvd-rg",
   "ResourceGroupNameAutomation": "proj-00016-automation-rg",
   "RunbookLogoffShutdown": "ARMLogoffAndShutdown",
   "SessionThresholdPerCPU": 0.75,
   "TimeDifference": "-3:00"
}
'@
}

& .\path\to\webhook-script.ps1 -WebHookData $mockWebhookPayload
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mathias... it work perfectly.